# Specific memory limitations of Pig LOAD statement?

Tags: memory, hadoop, apache-pig

**Simple question:**

What is the memory limitation of the Pig LOAD statement?

**More detailed question:**

Is there any way to relate available physical resources (disk, RAM, CPU) to the maximum size of a directory that a Pig LOAD statement can handle?

**Scenario:**

A research project is using a Pig script that is trying to load a directory containing 12,000+ files with a total size of 891GB in a single Pig LOAD statement, copied below. The files are gzipped WAT files which describe, in raw text, a collection of web pages. When run, the job appears to crash/hang/freeze our cluster every time. Since we are all new to Hadoop, the suspicion has been on resources and configuration until I finally was able to review the code.

```
-- load data from I_WATS_DIR 
Orig = LOAD '$I_WATS_DIR' USING org.archive.hadoop.ArchiveJSONViewLoader('Envelope.ARC-Header-    Metadata.Target-URI','var2...','var3...','var4...{1,2,3,4} as
(src:chararray,timestamp:chararray,html_base:chararray,relative:chararray,path:chararray,text:chararray,alt:chararray);
```

**Details:**

CLUSTER

1 front end node, 16 cores, 64GB RAM, 128GB swap, NameNode

3 compute nodes, 16 cores, 128GB RAM, 128GB swap, DataNode

TEST JOB 1

Same script referenced above, loading a directory with 1 file

Resident memory reported 1.2GB

Input: 138MB

Output: 207MB

Reduce input records: 1,630,477

Duration: 4m 11s

TEST JOB 2

Same script, 17 files

Resident memory: 16.4GB

Input: 3.5GB

Output: 1.3GB

Reduce input records: 10,648,807

Duration: 6m 48s

TEST JOB 3

Same script, 51 files

Resident memory: 41.4GB

Input: 10.9GB

Output: not recorded

Reduce input records: 31,968,331

Duration: 6m 18s

**Final thoughts:**

This is a 4 node cluster with nothing else running on it, fully dedicated to Cloudera Hadoop CDH4, running this 1 job only. Hoping this is all the info people need to answer my original question! I strongly suspect that some sort of file parsing loop that loads 1 file at a time is the solution, but I know even less about Pig than I do about Hadoop. I do have a programming/development background, but in this case I am the sys admin, not the researcher or programmer.

Comment: At what point does the job hang?  Are the map tasks successfully launched, but never complete?  Or is it before that, such that you never even see it appear on the job tracker?

Comment: No it definitely appears on the job tracker and begins mapping. CPU spikes to 100%, RAM appears to fill up completely (e.g. 64GB), and the cluster drops to concerning health (disk swapping errors) and eventually bad health. Also progress slows to a crawl, let's say the first 20% moves ahead normally, and then the next 1% will take 8+ hours.

Comment: Also the number of waiting tasks in the JobTracker spike quickly up to 100k+ and then decrease very slowly.

Comment: How much storage do you have on HDFS?  On the jobtracker report for the job, what are the values of FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN and HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN?

Comment: After those test jobs, I decided to re-run the script this morning and observe. Of course, now that I have posted about it, the job is running and so far has not crashed or hung the server. CPU is at 100%, and disk swapping is occurring, but not to the level that it is crashing.

Comment: At 60% complete, here are the numbers you asked for. FILES_BYTES_WRITTEN = 1,231,962,944,944, HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN = 0

Comment: I just bought Programming Pig, the official O’Reilly book, to look up some more info on this. FYI:
 
Pig Latin, a Parallel Dataflow Language 
 
Pig Latin is a dataflow language. This means it allows users to describe how data from one or more inputs should be read, processed, and then stored to one or more outputs in parallel. These data flows can be simple linear flows like the word count example given previously. They can also be complex workflows that include points where multiple inputs are joined, and where data is split into multiple streams to be processed by different operators.

Comment: To be mathematically precise, a Pig Latin script describes a directed acyclic graph (DAG), where the edges are data flows and the nodes are operators that process the data. This means that Pig Latin looks different from many of the programming languages you have seen. There are no if statements or for loops in Pig Latin.

Comment: This is because traditional procedural and object-oriented programming languages describe control flow, and data flow is a side effect of the program. Pig Latin instead focuses on data flow. For information on how to integrate the data flow described by a Pig Latin script with control flow, see Chapter 9 .
 
Gates, Alan (2011-09-29). Programming Pig (Kindle Locations 293-303). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Comment: What is the local (not HDFS) disk capacity of each node?

Comment: It's going to be a little complicated due to the way our system is set up. We are tenants on a community cluster. There are several mount points. Without getting into more details, is there a way to gauge how much input data a given cluster with given # of nodes, CPU, RAM, disk, etc. can handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of your cluster and the amount of data your pushing through it, it sounds like you are running out of space during the map/shuffle phase of the job.  The temporary data is sent over the network, uncompressed, and then written to disk on the reducer before being processed in the reduce phase.  One thing you can try is to compress the output of the mappers by setting `mapred.map.compress.output` to `true` (and specifying the desired codec).

But with only four nodes, I suspect you're just trying to do too much at once.  If you can, try splitting up your job into multiple steps.  For example, if you are doing the standard word count example, do the word count over small portions of your data, and then run a second MR program that sums those counts.